# Check cipher suite used in JMeter HTTP Request with https and TLS

Tags: java, ssl, soap, jboss, jmeter

I have a JBoss EAP 6.3 server on localhost with a SOAP service on it which I am testing with Jmeter 2.11 and HTTP Request samplers.

Now I want to analyze the impact on performance using HTTPS with TLSv1 when consuming the SOAP service. For testing this I am looping 1 thread with 8 HTTP Requests, of which 4 use HTTP on port 8080 and the same 4 again with HTTP**S** on port 8443.

My first idea was to use Wireshark to see if the HTTPS requests are encrypted and spy on the SSL handshake to see the used cipher suite, but I can't listen on the loopback interface (I simply don't have one it seems).

**So my question is:** Can I somehow detect which cipher suite JMeter uses for https requests, for example from JMeter log files or using a Beanshell PostProcessor and read this information from some of the provided variables (ctx, prev, log, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the informationen I need - the used cipher suite - in the console output of JMeter:

```
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
```

For this information to be displayed I went to the **system.properties** file in the JMeter directory and uncommented the following line in the "SSL debugging" section:

```
javax.net.debug=sslctx,session,sessioncache
```